# No such module "_concurrency"

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, react-native, arm64

im tring to build my iOS App but it fails with next error:

No such module "_concurrency"
[image]

I undestand that the compiler that xcode is running has this module deprecated.

I dont know how to solve it.
Please, I need help.

Config:
"react-native": "0.64.3",
"expo": "^43.0.3",
"react-native-fbsdk-next": "^9.0.0",
"expo-modules-core": "~0.4.10"

xcode version: "12.5.1"
iOS Deployment Target 12.0
swift: 5.4.2

Comment: Concurrency is iOS 15

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your version of Xcode is too old (12.5.1). You'll need to upgrade to 13.

Comment: I hope my hackintosh doesn't break...